# Ruby on Rails : How to see information in render form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby On Rails.I'd like to understand how RoR works. I have the following url when i want to edit user informations:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/3/edit
```

Here is my controller :

```
  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end
```

The form is :

```
<div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
<div class="column">

<h1>Profil</h1>

<div class="ui form segment">

<%= render "form" %>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<%= link_to 'Show', @user %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

I understand that the form is print by the code `<%= render "form" %>`. I'd like to know how to see what contains form ? Which informations are available in form ?

Comment: If you mean you want to see the content of the form, you can just look into `views/users/_form.html.erb` file.

Comment: `<%= render "form" %>` will render what the file at app/views/users/_form.html.erb contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

`<%= render "form" %>`

renders partial. You should find file with name `_form.html.erb`

or read more about partials in [GUIDE](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

Answer (score 0):

The `render` method is used to load a partial. A partial is basically repeated fragment of code in a view. To keep things dry, you separate it out in a partial and then pass it to the `render` method to `render` it.

In your case, the `form` is a partial.

You will most probably find it at `app/views/users/_form.html.erb`

Partials are always prefixed with a `_` in their filename.